# connecting tomcat webapp running in docker container to mysql

Tags: docker

I have mysql server running in centos host and I want to deploy my war in tomcat inside docker container in same host. Any idea how can I connect mysql from inside the container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you can do to connect to the DB (mysql) from the App (tomcat).
There are two ways you can do this

1. By using links
2. Manual way by providing the IP address of db to the tomcat app

Example-1 (Links)

- Get your mysql container up:

> "docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="xxxx" -e
>   MYSQL_DATABASE="xxxx" -d mysql"

- You now need to build and run the application container which must
  know where is the db instance. You will have to figure out where you
  provide the link to the db in your application. It can be in the code
  or in a property file. You can use volume to mount this file into the
  application container. You will also be able to modify them on the
  fly because they will be accessible to you on the host system. This
  is one example of doing this: docker

> docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name app --link db:db -v
>   $PWD/webapp:/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ app

- Here we are using the image app where i am mounting webapp folder
  from my docker base folder. This folder is having my code which i am
  pushing to the tomcat's webapp folder. I am also pushing the
  properties file to the appropiate location on the container where the
  mysql connection is mentioned like this :
  "jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/dbname" . We are mapping port 8080 of
  the container to the port 8080 of the host. We are mapping container
  db with container app. This creates an entry on /etc/hosts file - "db
  ipname". So both containers can communicate with each other even if
  we restart the db container (which changes the IP). Links will update
  the host entry with the new IP.

Example 2:

- Up the db container
- Get the IP of the db container using this "docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container-name/ID"
- Up the app containers with volumes where you can edit the jdbc url on your host.
- Change the IP to db container's IP and this should be able to establish the connection

---

If you want to use Host's mysql

> docker run -d --net=host --name app image command

Do let me know if you need any further explanation.
You can go through the topics on volumes, links from docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/

Comment: Thanks Chandan for replying. Actually I don't want to deploy mysql in container. I want mysql to run in host itself and then I have to connect it to tomcat app which is running in container

Comment: BTW I already tried using ip address of host to connect to mysql but it didn't work inside container

Comment: I have updated the answer with one sample command for "--net=host"

Comment: it should just work as connecting remote mysql over TCP. would you please make sure your mysql listens to TCP and ip addr not 127.0.0.1? at least your mysql should listen to `127.17.0.1` where it's the docker host ip for containers

Comment: @ChandanNayak hi very much interesting, i am trying for the past two days, but i can't achieve it, will u give a sample or suggest me a way