# Connect tomcat container to mysql container

Tags: mysql, tomcat, docker

I am trying to connect a container with tomcat to a container with mysql in order to deploy an app. I have reproduced the same into a vagrant machine (tomcat 6, mysql 5.6) but now I want to do it using docker containers.
I used this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679661/connecting-tomcat-webapp-running-in-docker-container-to-mysql) with some extra additions.
For the mysql container I run:

```
sudo docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_USER=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e MYSQL_DATABASE=my_database_name -d mysql:5.6
```

For the Tomcat container

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name tomcat --link mysql:mysql -v $PWD/webapp:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps tomcat:6
```

Also I have the folder webapp/with_my_app.war. So far so good.

This specific app needs some config in the WEB-INF/context.xml file, so I run

```
docker exec -it tomcat bash
```

Then I updated and installed vim and finally edit the context.xml file and restarted tomcat.

But I cannot access my app at localhost:8080/with_my_app

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably need a bit more info and any specific errors. For starters though, I would externalize WEB-INF/context.xml via a volume so you can edit it outside the container and make sure it persists through restarts. Then use `docker exec` from the tomcat container to try to ping/access the MySql container. If you get that far, it will help to sort out what you need to do next.

Comment: Which entrypoint are you using to communicate with mysql container from your application?

Comment: @Idg I don't know how to externalise the contect.xml but after restarts I checked it again and the content persisted through the restarts. So I guess that is not the problem. I pinged to the db (nice one btw) and it worked fine.

Comment: @GianArb What do you mean? Is it in the web.xml file or it can be anywhere? I am just deploying the app so I don't know exactly how it works. But when I tested in the vm, I had to configure only the content.xml file and then it worked.

"Highlights" from Tomcat's error log:     

1(java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused) 
   
2(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure)
3(org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure)

Answer (score 0):

Include `--cap-add SYS_PTRACE` while running tomcat container.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --cap-add SYS_PTRACE ......
```